# How to move an elements list into another element with the best performance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, move, element

I have two lists with a lot of items "more than 50" and I need to move to an individual element with all its events.

```html
<div id="container">     
     <div><ul id="g1"></ul><ul id="g2"></ul></div>
     <div><ul id="gFill"></ul></div>
<div>
```

I have the same number of items in "g1" and "g2" lists, and I need to move them to "gFill" in an interleaved way.

I'm doing with the following script:

```js
var gFill = $("#gFill");
var g1 = $("#g1");
var g2 = $("#g2");
while (true) {
  if ($("li", g1).size() >= $("li", g2).size()) {
    $('li:first', g1).appendTo(gFill);
  }
  else {
    $('li:first', g2).appendTo(gFill);
  }
  if ($("li", g1).size() < 1 && $("li", g2).size() < 1) {
    break;
  }
}
```

Despite moving items good, the performance is too slow. I must to improve the performance, how can I do it?

After that I need the method of inverse, I need to move the items if "gFill" to "g1" and "g2", I did it but is very slow too.

```js
var gIn1 = [], gIn2 = [];
var g1 = $("#g1");
var g2 = $("#g2");
$("li", "#container").each(function (i, e) {
  var item = this;
  if ($("li", g1).size() <= $("li", g2).size()) {
    $(this).appendTo(g1);
  }
  else {
    $(this).appendTo(g2);
  }
});
```

It would be great to go asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

I would move the elements all in one operation, most of the issue here is likely due to the multiple `appendTo`s to `#gFill`, you should try to make it just one call to `appendTo`.

First, I'd collect all the `<li>`s:

```
var $lis = $('#g1 li, #g2 li');
```

Then, I'd create an empty array to hold all the `<li>`s:

```
var stack = [];
```

Then, I'd loop through the stack, counting from 0 and halfway forward.

```
for (var i = 0, j = half; i < half; i++, j++)
```

So, I'd end up with something like:

```
(function ($) {
  var $lis = $('#g1 li, #g2 li');
  var half = $lis.length / 2;
  var stack = [];

  for (var i = 0, j = half; i < half; i++, j++) {
    stack.push(
      $lis.eq(i),
      $lis.eq(j)
    );
  }

  $('#gFill').append(stack);
}(jQuery));
```

You can move them back by going through stack and diving them up by their index.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/crswll/L62p2tyy/1/